# Which mazes in Europe are worth visiting with children?

Tags: europe, children, activities

I recently saw a maize maze near my home town in the East Midlands, UK.  However, the functionality was fairly basic.

The children loved it though so I wanted to explore other maze options across Europe.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

EDIT TO ADD:  Please can you annotate your answer with facts, references, white papers and wherever possible independent verified sources assuring that the maze is indeed 1. A maze and 2. Enjoyable by those entering the Maze.  Please avoid sponsored corporate websites for facts as they may not be independent and acting as a front for the maze-owner.

In addition, please avoid using any of the following subjective terms including fun, enjoyment, well-worth-the-money or agreeable.  Please discard any opinions that were broadcast by children as their judgement cannot be held to the standard required for SE. Children cannot accurately gauge their own enjoyment levels - an algorithm will suffice for computing the optimum amount of fun that can be enjoyed per £ of maze payment.

Comment: Are amusement parks that have a maze also appropriate for you? I know a rather good amusement park in Continental Europe that also has a maze as one of their attractions.

Comment: Absolutely :-) Drop it in the answer section

Comment: This question is too subjective. We can't provide opinion-based recommendations. If you give us a short list of specific criteria (designed for children under 8 years old and costs less than X, or whatever) we will be much better able to answer your question.

Comment: Given there are quite possibly hundreds of mazes in Europe suitable for at least some children, I fear this isn't a good fit (as it stands) for our Q&A format

Comment: @Gagravarr - since you don't know if there are hundreds of mazes and you clearly have no real interest in a question about mazes why do you feel the need to try to answer this question?

Comment: @Flimzy - the question is no more subjective than any travel question discussing activities.  The moderation on this forum is ridiculous, honestly.  A simple list of mazes by Travel SE members who have been there and recommend them.  If you have not been to a maze and/or you do not feel it can be recommended then you should not even be on this question let alone trying to get it closed.  SE seems to be "I cannot answer X therefore X is not a valid question."   There is a perfectly reasonable answer below these comments.  When it comes to my children, I don't consider other parents opinions...

Comment: ...as subjective.  They are informed, considered and most likely reliable.  Kids are not code.  Subjectivity is essential for recommending activities.  Price is not a concern so it does not feature in the question.  I have never heard of a children's maze having an age limit so that is not a concern.  The brief is simple - have you been to a maze in Europe that you would recommend for children.  I suggest the moderation nazi's find another question to close.

Comment: @Venture2099: We don't allow open-ended questions about "activities" either. If you search the site you'll find that such questions are always closed very quickly.

Comment: `A simple list of mazes by Travel SE members who have been there and recommend them` -- We don't do that. 1) So called "list questions" are off-topic, because there is no authoritative answer. 2) We don't do polls ("Who has been to a maze?") 3) We don't do recommendations.

Comment: It may be that this makes our moderation "ridiculous" by someone's standards, but it works well for us, and it allows us to maintain a high standard of quality. If you're interested in open-ended discussion about recommendations, there are many other Internet forums for such things.

Comment: @Flimzy The moderation policy is not ridiculous.  The draconian interpretation you are invoking is ridiculous.

Comment: @Venture2099 I'd say I've visited well over 2 dozen mazes in Europe, which is how I can feel confident saying there'll be hundreds of them. Some brilliant for adults and large children, some only of interest to very small ones. A question that would produce hundreds of answers (eg one answer for one or two mazes) is not a good fit for your format, sorry

Comment: @Venture2099: My goal is to help you focus your question to be within our site guidelines. I don't believe I'm making any "draconian interpretations"--I'm following the site guidelines (as are many others here). This is not the place to debate well-established site policy. I encourage you to clarify your question to be within site guidelines, or you can raise the issue on Meta if you honestly feel you are being treated somehow unfairly.

Comment: I think the question is fine how it is.  Kindly unlock it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One place I can recommend heartily for nearly anyone with children is the Dutch amusement park De Efteling in Kaatsheuvel, Netherlands. It is one of the oldest amusement parks in the world, with parts of it dating back to before Disneyland California. Like you ask, it has a nice hedge maze, but that's only a small part of the park.

I personally refer to the park as "a poor man's Disneyland": It is based around the same original fairytales as the classic Disney films like Snow White, Sleeping Beauty, Cinderella,... However, they're far less commercialized and the park itself is not as big, making a day excursion feasible. There are a number of interesting rides for all ages, with fast rides, slow rides and a lot of animatronics. There are also several theaters that have a number of shows per day, including a magical tree for children and a medieval show with horses, ravens and mechanical dragons.

I realize this probably sounds like an advertisement for the park, but I feel like it's a really good idea for a day trip. If you're just going there for the maze, it's really expensive, but if you go there for the total package, it's totally worth it.